# ASP.NET Mvc 3 Model binding to a collection not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am trying to create an edit form for a collection of items. The List is null and when I check the ModelState its Valid property is "true" and it has 0 keys. There are no required properties on the People entity.

View

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdatePeople", "People", FormMethod.Post }))
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>


 @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.People[i].FirstName)



       </div>
     }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePeople(List<People> items)
{                    
 // items is null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Action Method receives not the model of type `List<People>` it receives your ViewModel.

I don't see your model definition, so a little sample.

It look like that you have a Model which has a property named `People` of type `List<People>`.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<People> People { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

If you now submit your Form, MVC try to Bind it. Your action method said it receives a

```
List<People>
```

but your send `MyViewModel`.

So if you change your action method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePeople(MyViewModel model)
{                    
    // model.People exists

}
```

it will work.

If your ViewModel has only the one propertie `People` you don't need this model. 
You can pass `List<Person>` to your view.

**hope this helps**

Comment: The Action method will bind to whatever is passed to it that it can match with what is sent with the request. It does *not* have to be the view model that was passed to the view. It can be random properties, or any model class where the properties line up with parameter names.

Comment: Yes i know how the ModelBinder works. But this is the problem here. You are right, maybe i should make this more clear.